# How can I remove white space from a bootstrap container?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this website: https://acanhs.org/nhs-articles.html for some reason their is a lot of empty white space in the container. How can I change the height of this element.

My html:

```
<center>
    <section class="blog-posts grid-system">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="all-blog-posts">
            <center>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <div class="blog-post">
                    <div class="blog-thumb">
                      <img src="articlepics/Fitness.jpg" alt="" class="article">
                    </div>
                    <div class="down-content">
                      &emsp;
                      <h4>Fitness</h4>
                      <ul class="post-info">
                        <li>Mohammad Al-Wazzan</li>
                        <li>3/11/2020</li>
                      </ul>
                    <div class="btn download" onclick="window.location='articlepdfs/Fitness.pdf';">
                        <div class="cloud">
                        <div class="arrow"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <div class="blog-post">
                    <div class="blog-thumb">
                      <img src="articlepics/الأمير.jpg" alt="" class="article">
                    </div>
                    <div class="down-content">
                      &emsp;
                      <h4>الأمير الراحل … أمير الإنسانية</h4>
                      <ul class="post-info">
                        <li>Mohammad Al-Obaidi</li>
                        <li>3/10/2020</li>
                      </ul>
                    <div class="btn download" onclick="window.location='articlepdfs/الأمير الراحل … أمير الإنسانية.pdf';">
                        <div class="cloud">
                        <div class="arrow"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <div class="blog-post">
                    <div class="blog-thumb">
                      <img src="articlepics/Uyghur.jpg" alt="" class="article">
                    </div>
                    <div class="down-content">
                      &emsp;
                      <h4>Uyghur Muslims</h4>
                      <ul class="post-info">
                        <li>Khalid Kooheji</li>
                        <li>27/9/2020</li>
                      </ul>
                      <div class="btn download" onclick="window.location='articlepdfs/Uyghur Muslims.pdf';">
                        <div class="cloud">
                        <div class="arrow"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="post-options">
                        <div class="row">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <div class="blog-post">
                    <div class="blog-thumb">
                      <img src="articlepics/Corona.jpg" alt="" class="article">
                    </div>
                    <div class="down-content">
                      &emsp;
                    <h4>Corona Virus: A New World</h4>
                      <ul class="post-info">
                        <li>Majed Al-Shaheen</li>
                        <li>27/9/2020</li>
                      </ul>
                      <div class="btn download" onclick="window.location='articlepdfs/Corona Virus A New World.pdf';">
                        <div class="cloud">
                        <div class="arrow"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                      <div class="post-options">
                        <div class="row">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <div class="blog-post">
                    <div class="blog-thumb">
                      <img src="articlepics/اقرأ.jpg" alt="" class="article">
                    </div>
                    <div class="down-content">
                      &emsp;
                      <h4>التعلم عبادة</h4>
                      <ul class="post-info">
                        <li>Omar Sheir</li>
                        <li>23/9/2020</li>
                      </ul>
                      <div class="btn download" onclick="window.location='articlepdfs/التعلم عبادة.pdf';">
                        <div class="cloud">
                        <div class="arrow"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                      <div class="post-options">
                        <div class="row">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <div class="blog-post">
                    <div class="blog-thumb">
                      <img src="articlepics/الصدقة.jpg" alt="" class="article">
                    </div>
                    <div class="down-content">
                      &emsp;
                      <h4>الصدقة</h4>
                      <ul class="post-info">
                        <li>Ahmad Al-Mazrouei</li>
                        <li>20/9/2020</li>
                      </ul>
                      <div class="btn download" onclick="window.location='articlepdfs/الصدقة.pdf';">
                        <div class="cloud">
                        <div class="arrow"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                      <div class="post-options">
                        <div class="row">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </center>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    </center>
```

What can I add to reduce the height?......................................................................................................

Comment: you can start by using the inspector in your browser to see which element it's creating the white space or the unwanted height... then you can work out which classes are applying it

Comment: as much as i saw some elements have min-height start by removing that

Comment: Do you have your css file?

Comment: just see your <section class="blog-posts grid-system">, there is `.blog-posts {
    margin-top: 100px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You have margins and paddings at the top and down.You can try these:

```
.blog-posts {
    margin-top: 0;
 }

.footer-distributed {
 background-color: #2c292f;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: left;
 font: bold 16px sans-serif;
 padding: 50px 50px 60px 50px;
 margin-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh thanks everyone I fixed it by changing

```
.blog-posts .down-content {
    padding: 0px;
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;
    border-left: 1px solid #eee;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    min-height: 45em;
}
```

to

```
.blog-posts .down-content {
    padding: 0px;
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;
    border-left: 1px solid #eee;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    min-height: 35em;
}
```

in my css file